# How to download whole file from website

Tags: java, io, inputstream

I folow this example: http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-download-file-from-website-java-jsp

```
File file = new File("path/to/file/test.txt");
FileInputStream fis= new FileInputStream(file);
ServletOutputStream out = response.getOutputStream();

byte[] outputByte = new byte[4096];
//copy binary contect to output stream
while(fis.read(outputByte, 0, 4096) != -1)
{
    out.write(outputByte, 0, 4096);
}
fis.close();
out.flush();
out.close();
```

problem is that download file is still incomplete. At the end of file there is still missing some characters

so I try another example:

```
File file = new File("path/to/file/test.txt");
FileInputStream fis= new FileInputStream(file);


IOUtils.copy(fis,response.getOutputStream());
fis.close();
```

download file is complete. So my question is why first example doesnt work and is second example is correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if that is cause but could you replace this

```
//copy binary contect to output stream
while(fis.read(outputByte, 0, 4096) != -1)
{
    out.write(outputByte, 0, 4096);
}
```

with

```
int length=-1;
while ( (length = fis.read(outputByte, 0, 4096)) != -1) {
    out.write(outputByte, 0, length);
}
```

and let us know how it goes?

Comment: yes it works thx a lot. And what about second example. Is it correct way how to download file too ?

Comment: @hudi If `IOUtils` is from `apache.commons.io` then it is kind of based on first example so it is OK to use it.

Comment: keep in mind this is a blocking loop, so if you are multi-threading this, and need to be able to cancel, you'll want to switch to using channel based io.  See here:  http://thomaswabner.wordpress.com/2007/10/09/fast-stream-copy-using-javanio-channels/

Answer (score 1):

the value returned from `InputStream.read()` is important, use it!