# How to wait for user decision when downloading file

Tags: java

I want to continue with this question: [How to download whole file from website](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14947413/how-to-download-whole-file-from-website). I find out that downloading a file is an automatic process and it doesn't wait for user decision cancel/save. So for example user writes url to download file and wait 1 minute. The file automatically starts downloading (I am using firefox) probably to the memory of the browser and when file is download then it continues processing code where I have logger "file successfully download" but there is still pop up window with decision cancel/save. So my question how I can wait for this decision and react on this.

Comment: Is this issue not specific to the browser?

Comment: in chromium download file is automatic (default setting) and it doesnt show any pop up window so I just for case write my browser

Answer (score 0):

Let's presume that you have an object that performs a download. You can make it implement Runnable and then make it run as a separate thread.

You can have a method called setDestination(String), and a method called cancel().

Cancel would be something like that:

```
public synchronized void cancel() {
    this.cancelled = True;
}
```

And in the part where you actually perform the download you'd have a

```
if (this.cancelled) {
    //remove downloaded data
    return; //Exit from the download function
}
```

for the setDestination you would need to do something similar, store the download to a tempfile and at the end move it to the file indicated by destination.

Comment: but still I dont know when to call method cancel

Comment: When user presses a button to cancel?

Comment: and how I can figure out in java code ? I dont have any form there